# how to convert list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a text file like that:

```
{'XXX': [0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.029353, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724, ...], 'YYY': [0.922724, 0.922724, 0.922724], ... }
```

That when I load in python using `with open` it says that its type is a list, when I has the dictionary structure.

I want to convert this list into a dictionary, and I'm trying using: `ast.literal_eval()` but it says that the string is malformated.

How can I convert this "list" into a dictionary???

Comment: You need to show exactly how you're loading it, and how you're determining it's a list.

Comment: Can you show us your code? My assumoption is that you are doing `with open(...) as f: data = f.readlines()`. This will be a list of all the lines. You have to evaluate the first line.

Comment: I am using with open(filename1, 'r') as f to read the file.

Then, for iterating all lines: for line in f:

And then, I get the lines using: v=line.split('\t')

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you almost have JSON in your text file, except that the single quotes should be double quotes...

```
import json
results = list()
with open('file.txt') as text_file:
    for line in text_file.readlines():
        results.append(json.loads(line.replace("'", '"')))
```

Of course, that assumes there's nothing else in that file that would break the JSON parser.